# extracting database rows from an array within a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to extract 4 rows of product prices from a database table.

AU$ 11.00

AU$ 19.00

AU$ 32.00

AU$ 52.00

When i execute the code below i only retrieve the last value AU$ 52.00 from the database.

```
Array ( [CURRENCY] => AU$ 52.00 )
```

This is my code

```
$sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT monthly FROM products');

foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
    $price = '<small>AU$</small> ' . number_format($row->monthly, 2) . '<br>';
}

$currency = array(
    'CURRENCY' => $price,
);

print_r($currency['CURRENCY']);
die();
?>
```

Probably overlooking somthing simple but my head is all bitter and twisted now. Any help will be useful. Thanks in advance

EDIT TO QUESTION

This will be a currency converter so the code below may help with how it will work

```
$currencies = array('AUD', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'THB');

$get_cur = Input::get('currency');

if(isset($get_cur) === true && in_array($get_cur, $currencies) === true) {
    $_SESSION['currency'] = $get_cur;
} else if (isset($_SESSION['currency']) === false) {
    $_SESSION['currency'] = 'AUD';
}

include 'currency/' . $_SESSION['currency'] . '.php';
```

From each linked currency will go to AUD, USD, GBP etc etc

```
<a href="?currency=AUD">
```

Linked to AUD.php which is the code from the original question. This is why i need to link

```
$currency['CURRENCY']
```

This will be the defined name in the array of each currency.

Hope this helps

EDIT TO QUESTION #2

```
<?php
// Currency Covert Class
class CurrencyConverter {

    public function convert($amount, $from, $to) {
        $data = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=' . $amount . '&from=' . $from . '&to=' . $to);

        preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/", $data, $converted);

        $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);

        return $converted;
    }

}
////////////////////////

$currencies = array('AUD', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'THB');

$get_lang = Input::get('currency');

if(isset($get_lang) === true && in_array($get_lang, $currencies) === true) {
    $_SESSION['currency'] = $get_lang; //Get's the currency from whichever currency is selected from the $currencies = array('AUD', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'THB');
} else if (isset($_SESSION['currency']) === false) {
    $_SESSION['currency'] = 'AUD'; //If no currency selected, then default is AUD
}

include 'currency/' . $_SESSION['currency'] . '.php'; //Selects the currenct .php file eg; 'AUD', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'THB'

//If AUD.php then it $_GET currency eg; ?currency=AUD, ?currency=USD, ?currency=GBP

// This is AUD.php  (DEFAULT CURRENCY)
$sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT monthly FROM products');

foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
    $currency = array(
        'CURRENCY' => '<small>AU$</small> ' . number_format($row->monthly, 2),
    );
}

// This is USD.php  
$converter = new CurrencyConverter;

$sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT monthly FROM products');

foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
    $currency = array(
        'CURRENCY' => '<small>US$</small> ' . number_format($converter->convert($row->monthly, 'AUD', 'USD'), 2),
    );
}

//So you can see that all the currency .php files have the key array word of 'CURRENCY', and this is how it will work from the $_SESSION['currency'] to the    $currency['CURRENCY'] array

//Then simply echo out $currency['CURRENCY'] and it will convert to each     $currencies = array('AUD', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'THB');

echo '<p>' . $currency['CURRENCY'] . '<span>' . $lang['PER_MONTH'] . '</span></p>'; 
?>
```

EDIT TO QUESTION #3

I think i have found the issue, overlooked by me. It is inside a nested foreach loop

```
$sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC');

foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
    if(escape($row->popular)) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-3 price-table ' . escape($row->popular) . '">';
    } else {
    echo '<div class="col-md-3 price-table">';
}
?>

<h3><strong><?php echo escape($row->name) ?></strong><br><?php echo $lang['PACKAGE'] ?></h3>

<?php

///HERE IS WHERE IT GETS PULLED IN FROM AUD.php, USD.php, GBP.php, etc etc///

///START OF AUD.php///  
$sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT monthly FROM products');

$currency = array();
$currency['CURRENCY'] = array();

foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
    array_push($currency['CURRENCY'],  '<small>AU$</small> ' . number_format($row->monthly, 2));
}
///END OF AUD.php///

echo '<p>' . implode($currency['CURRENCY'], ' <span>' . $lang['PER_MONTH'] . '</span>') . '</p>';
```

The arrays is below

```
Array
(
    [0] => AU$ 11.00
    [1] => AU$ 19.00
    [2] => AU$ 32.00
    [3] => AU$ 52.00
)
```

I need it like this to be able to convert the currencies. So i need this;

```
echo '<p>' . implode($currency['CURRENCY'], ' <span>' . $lang['PER_MONTH'] . '</span>') . '</p>';
```

To echo out below in the first pass of the loop

```
echo '<p> AU$ 11.00 <span>Per Month</span></p>';
```

And echo out below in the second pass of the loop

```
echo '<p> AU$ 19.00 <span>Per Month</span></p>';
```

And so on. At the moment i am getting all four values on every pass of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$currency = array();
$currency['currency'] = array()
foreach($sql->results() as $row) {

    array_push($currency['currency'],  '<small>AU$</small> ' . number_format($row->monthly, 2));
}

echo '<p>' . implode($currency['CURRENCY'], ' <span>' . $lang['PER_MONTH'] . '</span><br />') . </p>';
```

Now `foreach` will `push` a value into the array `$currency`, with the correct currency.

Comment: the output need to be     echo '<p>' . $currency['CURRENCY'] . '<span>' . $lang['PER_MONTH'] . '</span></p>';

Comment: I see what you are coming from, but this echo the string of all value 4 times. If you look at the original question, what i am trying to achieve is the echo of $currency['CURRENCY']

Comment: Basically, this is going to be a currency converter so  need to grab all 4 prices from the DB. As any foreach loop will echo each price within the DB

Comment: Still an Array to string conversion output.

Comment: OKay, i have edited the question again, i know it's not straight forward but there has to be a solution. Comments added to see my train of thought

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i know you understand the code, what $currency['CURRENCY'] needs to represent in AUD.php of let's say 1.00AUD and $currency['CURRENCY'] in USD.php needs to represent  0.7322 USD

Comment: It's simple logic, but the problem is that it only pulls the last value from the database

Comment: Ha Ha sorry, i already tried this and it just returns AU$ 11.00AU$ 19.00AU$ 32.00AU$ 52.00 in each value :-)  But we are on the right tracks

Comment: it is putting every value AU$ 11.00AU$ 19.00AU$ 32.00AU$ 52.00 with every past of the loop

Comment: I see only one loop! The `foreach`. It passes all the rows into an array. Then we `echo` one simple line with those four rows. Output should be 
`'<p>AU$ 11.00AU$ 19.00AU$ 32.00AU$ 52.00<span>Per month</span></p>`. I now see the problem. See the edit.

Comment: Have a look at the edit -- EDIT TO QUESTION #3 I think i have found the issue

Comment: Well if that's the solution please mark my answer as the correct one.

Comment: Well it's not because i still can't get it to work Ahhhhhh

Comment: `echo '<p>' . implode($currency['CURRENCY'], ' <span>' . $lang[PER_MONTH'] . '</span>') . '</p>';` This line should NOT be in a loop!

Comment: Well, i wll give you that is correct, but that i need it like this. Need the key and value output from the QUESTION #3 - Array
(
    [0] => AU$ 11.00
    [1] => AU$ 19.00
    [2] => AU$ 32.00
    [3] => AU$ 52.00
)  There has to be a way to do this, i'm just missing something obvious here

Comment: I'm under the impression that your code is different from the one posted here. With all my help you should've been able to fix it already.

Comment: Nah, the code is exactly how i have posted it, although snippets. Do you want me to post the whole section??

Comment: For the last time, before I throw in the towel. The array is good? You want to write the array to the page. Each entry should look like this:
`[currencystring] [amount] per month`. You have seperate files for each currency type. So `aud` Always outputs `aud`. No need to dynamically set that currency type once we've entered `aud.php`. If the above is true than the implode should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You arent adding the value in your loop so you only get the last value in $price

```
foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
  $price = '<small>AU$</small> ' . number_format($row->monthly, 2) . '<br>';
  $currency[]=array('CURRENCY' => $price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this. it will do it perfectly

```
  $sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT monthly FROM products');
  $currency = array();
  $i=0;
  foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
      $price = '<small>AU$</small> ' . number_format($row->monthly, 2) . '<br>';

      $currency['CURRENCY'][$i] = $price;
      $i++;
  }



  print_r($currency['CURRENCY']);
  ?>
```

Comment: Gives a Array to string conversion - look at other comments

Answer (score -1):

Close `foreach` loop after you have assigned price to currency.

```
$currency = array();
foreach($sql->results() as $row) {
    $price = '<small>AU$</small> ' . number_format($row->monthly, 2) . '<br>';
$currency[] = $price;
}
```

Comment: This would still yield only the last result.

Comment: how is that?  for each loop price will be saved in currency array which is initially declared

Comment: Better, now it's just a copy of my answer.